# Fast way to write millions of small text files in Java?

Tags: java, file-io

I have to dump 6 million files which contain around 100-200 characters, and it's painfully slow. The actual slow part is the file writing, if I comment that part out (the call to the WriteSoveraFile method) the whole thing runs in 5-10 minutes.  As it is, I ran it overnight (16 hours) and got done with 2 million records.

1. is there any faster method?
2. Would I be better off creating an array of arrays and then dumping it all at once? (my system only has 4 GB, wouldn't it die from the 6 GB of data consumed by this?)

Here is the procedure:

```
public static void WriteSoveraFile(String fileName, String path, String contents) throws IOException {

    BufferedWriter bw = null;

    try {
        String outputFolderPath = cloGetAsFile( GenCCD.o_OutER7Folder ).getAbsolutePath() ;
        File folder = new File( String.format("%1$s/Sovera/%2$s/", outputFolderPath, path) );  

        if (! folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdirs();

/*          if (this.rcmdWriter != null)
              this.rcmdWriter.close();
*/        
        } 

        File file = new File( String.format("%1$s/%2$s", folder.getAbsolutePath(),fileName) );

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(contents);
            bw.close();
        }
/*      else {
            file.delete();  // want to delete the file??  or just overwrite it??
            file.createNewFile();*/

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (bw != null) bw.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, if you really have to write 6 million single files, it will take some time and it will be slow, because hard disks are slow. I do not know if you have influence on that, but at that scale of data I would consider using a database instead of files

Comment: Have you considered using a database management system for storing the metadata?

Comment: haha, no we can't use a database.  Basically we are interfacing with a medical application and to consume scanned documents they need a metadata file. Since we are converting 10+ years of data from a large enterprise, there is a ton of data.  So yeah we are stuck with millions of tiny files.

Comment: Remember that you only have to do this once. Well, once for testing and once for production. So, converting 10 years of data in 48 hours isn't an unreasonable thing in the overall scheme of things. That being said, you want to apply the optimizations suggested in other answers, just to make the first full run into something you can live with.

Comment: is using a DB can't be considered ? such a huge load of file could be considered as a problem in the concept.

Comment: Bob has a very good point.  We only need to run this once. Looks like it will take 48 hours of run time, so I'll start tonight (Friday).  So I'll add the code improvements as I can and consider SSD. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is almost certainly an OS filesystem issue; writing lots of files simply is slow. I recommend writing a comparison test in shell and in C to get an idea of how much the OS is contributing. Additionally, I would suggest two major tweaks:

- Ensure the system this is running on is using an SSD. Latency from seeking for filesystem journaling will be a major source of overhead.
- Multithread your writing process. Serialized, the OS can't perform optimizations like batch operation writing, and the `FileWriter` may block on the `close()` operation.

(I was going to suggest looking into NIO, but the APIs don't seem to offer much benefit for your situation, since setting up an mmapped buffer would probably introduce more overhead than it would save for this size.)

Comment: I actually tried it on a flash drive and the write operation dropped from 100 files/sec to 6 files/sec (USB2).  Agree we may need a faster machine, I am running it on a corporate laptop (w non-SSD disk).

Comment: @Rob Not a USB cheap-memory based "flash drive", a real one from Samsung or Intel. To add one to most laptops, you'd need eSATA. To get a comparison, try writing this to a RAM disk.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `nio` package. It is faster than `io`. Have a look: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/nio-vs-io.html

Benefits of NIO:
1. Buffer-oriented
2. Non-blocking IO

Because it is non-blocking, you can create a file, write data to it and it will be held in a buffer. Your application can then move on to the next file, write data to the buffer and so on and so forth. That means you do not have to wait for the data to actually be written before proceeding forward.

This will save you a lot of time considering millions of files. So even if it saves you quarter of a second, multiply it by one million and do the math =)

Comment: Applicable when writing a lot of data to a file. Not applicable when writing data to a lot of individual files; the filesystem operations are going to be blocking in the OS itself.

Comment: @chrylis Nothing can be done about it by Java. Any solution ? =) Plus, why not use a faster IO by using `nio` ? OS is already slow and on top of that use `io` package.

Answer (score 3):

As has been mentioned, your limiting factor is storage access not your code or the JVM.  There are a few things in your code that code be improved, but the changes would go unnoticed since the underlying bottleneck is the file IO.

There are some possible ways to speed up the process:

- Write to a faster drive (higher RPM hard drive or an SSD -- NOT a USB drive because USB communication is much slower than SATA.)
- Use multiple threads to write to a raided drive.  There are RAID levels (can't remember which ones) that support concurrent writes.
- Re-think the file structure such that it isn't necessary to have 6 million files.  If the files are in a single location, I'm not sure why you need so many small files.  The functionality could likely be accomplished by creating 1 or 2 larger file that takes all of the data.  You would just need to change the format and the reading component.  One file would be 200 chars * 2 * 6 million = ~2.4 GB (200 chars at 2 bytes/char times 6 million files).